# python exe errors when running by an external program

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze, file-not-found

I have python exe file which has been made using cx_Freeze. Basically The script uses the text file "XYZ.txt" to generate a word cloud. When I run the python exe file everything is fine and the code runs well, but I am planning to run it from an external program (a game which generates the text file) and when I'm trying to run it from that game, python exe runs but gives me the FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'XYZ.txt'. But the 'XYZ.txt' actually is in the same folder and at the same time. Besides, I tried to run the text file from that game and it opened but the python exe cannot find it.

I have also tried to run my game as administrator and then running the python exe and then I got: "dll load failed the specified module could not be found" instead of the previous error.

I would be thankful if anyone could help me with that.

Comment: Can you post your code, highlighting where the problem occurs?

Comment: The error occurs here:

with open('XYZ.txt','r',encoding="utf8") as infile:
    words = " ".join(infile)

But I need to mention again that the code runs fine when I run the python exe file directly, but when I call it inside the external application it shows that it cannot find "XYZ.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please give the absolute path for 'XYZ.txt' in your python code. I guess that might solve the problem.

Comment: Well it works when I give the absolute path but I want to share this file with others and in that case the path in the exe file won't be absolute for other computers. Do you have any solution for this case?

Comment: @Omid Perhaps you can then find the absolute path relative to the directory in which you install the game?

Comment: @KindStranger how can I do that?

Comment: @KindStranger, keep a configurable path for the XYZ.txt file in a separate config file(XYZ.cfg). You will need to read the config file to get the path of XYZ.txt in your python code. When you share the file with others, ask them to update the path (XYZ.cfg)